# Use Cellphone Vibrating motor in Mouse; on for 3sec off for 3 minutes

Tags: timing

I have electronic maintenance experience but it dates to 1985 (last use).
I can still solder well but I have forgotten all the electronic theory I once new except for VERY basic stuff.  So assume I'm a newbie.

I would like to install a micro vibrating motor (from an old flip style cell phone) that runs off 3.7 V inside a Micorsoft Optical USB Intellimouse and include a miniature on/off push button switch that turns the "timing" circuit on and off.

I would like to have the motor turn on for about 3 seconds(+-2 seconds) and turn off for about 3 minutes (+- 20 seconds) and continue that on/off cycle until I press the miniature push button switch to turn the "timing" circuit back off.

I would like the motor and "timing" circuit to use the mouse's internal +5v coming in via the USB cable.

The purpose of this project is to provide a mechanical means of periodically moving the mouse preventing my computer from entering sleep mode.  I cannot use a software solution because my workplace IT department has locked users out from changing configurations settings in Windows.

Is this possible?  Can you provide circuit diagram(s) and list of components required?

---

**Update:** I did not intend to start an ethics discussion with my question.  Respectfully, I submit some should not be so quick to judge. It is difficult to provide ALL the facts within a short post.

Prior to my initial post I did, in fact, discuss this with my boss & IT dept.  BOTH gave me the ok to investigate a timing circuit because

1. I am fortunate to work in a walled office that has a self-locking door; every time I exit, I must use my key to re-enter.
2. Most other users work in an open cubicle environment in multiple locations so IT is reluctant to change configuration settings that are managed via our network.
3. I spend a large amount of time in teleconferences and the time out issue has become a nuisance.

I have already demonstrated to IT two methods of moving the mouse w/o software:

- placing mouse on top of an analog watch w/ second hand.  Second hand movement is interpreted by mouse sensor as movement of mouse preventing timeout. Problem is it's hard to balance mouse on crystal face of watch consistently.
- I installed a cell phone vibrating motor with micro switch directly to 5v coming into mouse (motor runs until switched off hence the need for a timing circuit.)

If, after reading this update to my original post you still feel this is violating some ethical or legal rules, I withdraw my question and will seek advice elsewhere.  However, if you feel you can assist in clear conscience, please help me with a circuit design within the parameters originally specified.  Many thanks.

Comment: You may use a lm555c for the timer  this IC is specialized for timing works like that, so consider checking printerest or google image to see diverse diagrams & schematic on how to use it. This is the first step to think around your project

Comment: How about this: https://windowsreport.com/prevent-computer-from-sleeping-locking/

Comment: but: instead of modifying a mouse to mechanically vibrate, why not modify a keyboard to send a fake key press of an unmapped every few seconds? Or better even: Talk to the IT department about changing your user's lock screen settings.

Comment: francois P - thank you, I have searched Google some but haven't found a circuit that meets my cycle criteria and power source.  I will keep trying though.

Comment: Eugene Sh - thanks for the link but as I indicated, a software solution is not possible.  IT refuses to change settings nor will they allow users to install apps.

Comment: Some of the apps listed are "portable", I.e. not requiring installation.

Comment: Is there a *reason* given for the aggressive timeouts?  For example, do you work with data to which strict privacy controls applies?

Comment: Chris Stratton - my IT dept has set the time out on all computers to 4 minutes and yes it involves sensitive personal data being used.  Can you provide more specifics  on how to employ/use the ATtiny and N-FET you mentioned - I will google to see what I can find.  Thank you!  Mouse jiggler dongle is not an option; IT policy prevents users from using ANYTHING in USB ports other than keyboard & mouse.

Answer (score 1):

You may still be able to do this in software. Try saving this on your desktop as 'idle.vbs'. Double click it to run.

```
Dim objResult
' Prevent screen saver lock
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")    
i = 0

Do While i = 0
  objResult = objShell.sendkeys("{NUMLOCK}{NUMLOCK}")
  Wscript.Sleep (60000)
Loop
```

This script sends a double NumLock keypress every 60 s and keeps the OS awake with very little risk of you missing a number while typing. If that does prove to be a problem see if you can send a double Scroll Lock instead.